# Cannot bind DataGridComboBoxColumn to a view model collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a view model with a collection of items, each item has a collection of keys. I want to make DataGridComboBoxColumn to display a drop down list of the keys for each item. I have seen similar questions, but none of the answers helped me. When I run my application, all comboboxes are empty. Here is my xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestDataGridCombobox.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Keys}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=SelectedKey}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

And here is my view model:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestDataGridCombobox
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Item1" });
            Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Item2" });
            Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Item3" });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<MyItem> items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();        
        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {
                if (items == value)
                    return;
                items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyItem()
        {
            Keys.Add("Key1");
            Keys.Add("Key2");
            Keys.Add("Key3");
            SelectedKey = "Key1";
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name == value)
                    return;
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private string selectedKey;
        public string SelectedKey
        {
            get { return selectedKey; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedKey == value)
                    return;
                selectedKey = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> keys = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Keys
        {
            get { return keys; }
            set
            {
                if (keys == value)
                    return;
                keys = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Keys");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

And the view model is bound to window like this:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

I could use a templated column, but I'm interested in why this particular example doesn't work, are there any issues with the code? Or are there any limitations to DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or are there any limitations to `DataGridComboBoxColumn`?

Yes, there are some limitations. You can find them by reading the **Remarks** section in the [DataGridComboBoxColumn Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> To populate the drop-down list, first set the ItemsSource property for the ComboBox by using one of the following options:
>
> - A static resource. For more information, see [StaticResource Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension?view=netframework-4.7.1).
> - An x:Static code entity. For more information, see [x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-static-markup-extension?view=netframework-4.7.1).
> - An inline collection of [ComboBoxItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem?view=netframework-4.7.1) types.

There are a lot of workarounds to solve this issue, for example - as you wrote - you can use a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.7.1).

I hope it can help you.